# python request как правильно передать get запрос с параметрами

Tags: python, json, requests, get

Есть ответ от сервера в виде json , использовал метод get - запроса для библиотеки requet

Сам ответ такой:

```
{'EURUSD': 1.1245, 'GBPUSD': 1.3357}
```

Вопрос: как путем такого же запроса, но с используя парметры получить данные только допустим для  ключа `GBPUSD` , т.е мне нужен ответ от сервера не в полном обьеме (не все данные), а только часть

Мой код:

```
import requests

adress = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/1"

response = requests.get(adress)
# response_2 = requests.get(adress, params={"GBPUSD": ???})   -- ???
result = response.json()
```

Либо же я не правильно думаю таким образом получать данные, но смысл такой как мне фильтровать данные в get-запросе, чтобы уже получить отфильтрованные данные от сервера (который мне выдает большой обьем данных ввиде json)

Comment: по сути `requests.get(adress, params={"GBPUSD": ???}` сформирует HTTP-запрос: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/1?"GBPUSD"=???]

Comment: сорри... ошибся. Кавычки не надо...
[127.0.0.1:8000/test/1?GBPUSD=???]

Comment: Так тут всё завязано на то, как ваш сервер обрабатывает параметры запроса. Какие он параметры принимает. Универсальных рецептов нет, надо знать, какой у сервера `API`.

Answer (score -1):

Вот нашел более менее подходящий вариант:

response = requests.get(adress, timeout=3.05)

result = response.json()

print(result.get("EURUSD"))